# Display progress of exe installation from powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm installing a file through powershell silently, but would like to give feedback on the progress of the installation. I can't seem to find this information anywhere. This is the code I have for running the exe:

```
$exe = "wls1033_oepe111150_win32.exe"
$xmlLocation = Resolve-Path "silent_install.xml"
$xmlLocation = "-silent_xml=" + $xmlLocation
$installLogLoc = Resolve-Path "wls_install.log"
$installLogLoc = "-log=" + $installLogLoc
$AllArgs = @('-mode=silent', $xmlLocation, $installLogLoc)
$filePath = Resolve-Path $exe
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo.Filename = $filePath
$p.StartInfo.Arguments = $AllArgs
$p.Start();
$p.WaitForExit();
```

Is there even a way to do this? I do get a progress meter for the extraction process in an alternate command window that installs the exe, but other than that it sits for there about 10 minutes with no sort of indication.

Edit: So seeing as this isn't possible, is there a way to do an asynchronous pipeline call while running the exe?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm 99% sure that this is NOT possible. Your exe file is seperate process and not a PowerShell script. It will not be able to pass status messages to your PowerShell sessions. The only possibility would be to detect the setups log-file, tail it and update a progressbar in PowerShell based on keywords from the log. This is however a big task and something you need to customize for each setup file.

I would try to look into your exe file and see if it has a "basic ui" (or a similar type) mode that you can use instead of the silent option. A last alternative would be to repackage the setup with such an option(making installation automated with only progressbar). This solution would still only show the progressbar in a separate window and not in PowerShell itself.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible. I just wasn't sure if there was a class that monitored it that I didn't know of. I guess I could do a little cheat and monitor the output folder checking the size of it against a pre-determined maximum size with an async call with pipeline.